# get variable outside for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I create code like this:

```
for (var b = 0; b < parseDataArr.length; b++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < parseDataArr[b].data_item.length; c++) {
        for (var d = 0; d < parseDataArr[b].data_item[c].data_receipt.length; d++) {
            var kartonReceipt = parseDataArr[b].data_item[c].data_receipt[d].cartonIRBar
        }
    }
}
log.debug('carton for',cartonIRBar) // not all result for loop only last data has record
```

How do I get all the result data from `cartonIRBAr` without moving the `debug()` statement inside the loop?

Comment: Don't know what's unclear about this question @Daedalus et al.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It wasn't clear what problems the OP was having from their question's earlier wording.  That said, I don't see why this question should be reopened at present, unless it is just to close it as a duplicate of another question, like: "[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/785241)"

Comment: @Daedalus OP is not looking for an explanation about why their current approach doesn't work. They're looking for a solution to their problem. There might very well be a duplicate about collecting all values from deeply nested arrays, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen The other bit of info lacking clarity is if they meant to debug the value of `cartonIRBar`, which isn't defined anywhere in the code, or if it is just a typo and meant to be `kartonReceipt` instead.

Comment: @Daedalus That's a valid point, but we could at least give the question a fighting chance by asking for clarification.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Which is exactly what question closures are supposed to do, that way people don't answer questions with incomplete information.

Comment: @Daedalus Again, a fair point, but if there's *specific* information that we're lacking, it might be helpful to ask for that in a comment, in addition to voting to close?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Also a fair point, even if at the same time it doesn't always scale.  However, I'm not about to get into a close war even if I can; [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75554479/785241?noredirect=1#comment133300926_75554479) contains the details needing clarification; it is now up to the OP to clarify, and to the answerers to wait until that clarification is made(hopefully).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Please excuse my lack of timely responses; I seem to be experiencing some amount of lag on the site that I cannot replicate elsewhere.

Comment: @antechf11 inside those nested loops you are bound to get multiple values assigned to `kartonReceipt`, overwriting any previous value. What value do you want to log for `cartonIRBar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get information about all the `cartonIRBar` values in that deeply nested array, you need to accumulate those values into a data structure, like an array.

You could use a nested [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) approach:

```
const kartonReceipts = parseDataArr.flatMap(
  ({data_item}) => data_item.flatMap(
    ({data_receipt}) => data_receipt.flatMap(
      ({cartonIRBar}) => cartonIRBar
    )
  )
);
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const parseDataArr = [{
  data_item: [{
    data_receipt: [{
      cartonIRBar: 'value1'
    }]
  }]
}, {
  data_item: [{
    data_receipt: [{
      cartonIRBar: 'value2'
    }, {
      cartonIRBar: 'value3'
    }]
  }]
}];

const kartonReceipts = parseDataArr.flatMap(
  ({data_item}) => data_item.flatMap(
    ({data_receipt}) => data_receipt.flatMap(
      ({cartonIRBar}) => cartonIRBar
    )
  )
);

console.log(kartonReceipts);
```